# Can 'a system of rules that assigns [...] meaning in a definite way' be replaced with 'semantics'?

Tags: terminology, semantics, chomsky, meaning

<sub>Source: *An Introduction to Language* (10 ed, 2014) by V Fromkin, R Rodman, N Hyams. I, and not the book, bolded.</sub>

> > [p 7:] A person who knows a language has mastered
> >     **[1.]** a system of rules that assigns sound and
> >     **meaning** in a definite way for an infinite class of possible sentences.
> >     NOAM CHOMSKY, *Language and Mind*, 1968
>
> [p 9:] The way we are using the word grammar differs from most common usages.
>   In our sense, the grammar is the knowledge speakers have about the units
>   and rules of their language—rules for combining sounds into words (called
>   *phonology*), rules of word formation (called *morphology*), rules for combining
>   words into phrases and phrases into sentences (called *syntax*), as well as **[2.]** the
>   rules for assigning meaning (called *semantics*).

I am trying to conquer my failure to disambiguate 'meaning' and 'semantics' by asking whether one can substitute for the other in certain sentences and then by verifying the substitution. So can 'semantics' can be used to rewrite [p 7.]?
If so, is my [3.] correct; does [3.] mean the same thing as [1.]?

> **[3.]** A person who knows a language has mastered
>   <s>a system of rules that assigns sound and meaning</s> [phonology and semantics] in a definite way for an infinite class of possible sentences.

Comment: Editing a definition of language is not a good way to arrive at a definition of semantics.   "A system of rules that assigns meaning in a definite way" is very unclear.   Assigns meaning to what?   I think that you should look at definitions of semantics (I'm sure there are more than one) rather than trying to come up with one in the manner you descdribed.

Comment: You should consider editing this question.

Answer (score 3):

Chomsky (in this passage) defines universal grammar as "a system of rules that assigns sound and meaning in a definite way for an infinite class of possible sentences." He writes that it (=universal grammar) consists of three components: syntactic, semantic, and phonological.

He understands the syntactic component as the one defining an infinite class of possible sentences. The semantic and phonological components, he argues, are "purely interpretive" (p.111).

Now to your specific question. The problem is that **you misunderstand the relationship of synonymy and substitution**. Also, quite often the particular word choice is determined by stylistic or syntactic considerations. Just because you can't insert the word semantics in a particular sentence doesn't say much about the actual meaning of the term semantics. You clearly say that you're trying to understand the difference between two English words, meaning and semantics. That being said, **your extremely crude approach is wrong** (*can they be substituted in sentences?*). There are so many factors that affect word choice (morphosynstactic properties, register, etc.)

**As is, your question is misinformed because it is based on false assumptions and thus has no answer.**

Answer (score 1):

No. Here is some examples. "A system of rules that assigns […] meaning in a definite way is known as 'semantics'" cannot be changed to "Semantics is known as 'semantics'". Also, anybody who says "I'm trying to discover a system of rules that assigns […] meaning in a definite way" would not say "I'm trying to discover semantics". I don't understand the value of "[...]" in your question. Semantics does not do phonology, in case that is what you are asking. Or are you asking if Chomsky *thought* at the time that semantics does phonology (analogous to the current apparent belief that word order is determined by phonology)? It's not exactly clear what your question is.

In that historical context, your 3 is not a correct restatement of 1, since you failed to include syntax, which at the time (and as far as I know, still) has not been subsumed under phonology.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the [...] which I used to omit 'sound' as I am not asking about phonology at all in this question. My question is: `So can 'semantics' can be used to rewrite [p 7.]?`' Does this clarify?